# ArcGIS Javascript Web Map Printout with Popup Shown

Tags: arrays, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a working printing task that will simply use the ESRI Print Task to export to PDF like in this sample - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_print_webmap.html.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to include popups on the printout if the user has clicked on a feature and is displaying the popup at the time of printing.  I have not seen anyone asking the same question unfortunately and would like to have this feature on my print task.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using a customTextElement and the following code to pick up when the infoWindow selection changes: 
     dojoOn(map.infoWindow, "selection-change", function(){ 
            //build custom text here 
      }